# How to convert hex opacity value to decimal percantage Flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I see this article, but I couldn't reverse them to use [Gist](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/8710f6f752f6a0f2cae13abb538f0e8e)

I have a color as a hex value like '0xFF124365'

I can get its FF value, then I can convert it to the decimal 255.

everything was okay up to now.

I could not convert 255 to 100.

I want to generate percentage values like shown below.

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
```

how can I do more?

Answer (score 1):

```
double convert(int x) => x / 255 * 100;
```

Or to get is as int, rounded up:

```
int convert(int x) => (x / 255 * 100).round();
```